# JBoss EAP 6.3 Http Connector Settings

Tags: tomcat, jboss

I have been researching on Google for quite some time now to understand how a server accepts a http-request and processes them. If I understand right there should be a listener on port 8080 that always keeps listening for incoming http-requests and as soon as it receives a request it should be able to create a thread and delegate the work to that thread.

With the knowledge above, what I am trying to understand is what is max-connections and max-threads while setting up http-connector. Also if we don't explicitly specify these then what is the maximum value?

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
        <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
        <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
            <alias name="localhost"/>
            <alias name="example.com"/>
        </virtual-server>
    </subsystem>
```

To be very specific here are my questions in bullet form:

- Is max-connection=maximum http listeners that can process http-requests concurrently?
- Is max-threads=maximum threads that are created in internal thread pool that is used by http listener to delegate the work to?
- With default http connector settings as mentioned above, what is the default value of max-connections and max-threads
- What is the decision factor to set the max-connections and max-threads, is it dependent on the number of processors and available memory?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**max-connections:** The maximum number of connections that the server will accept and process at any given time.

If the max-connections attributes is not set on web subsystem connectors in standalone-(*).xml / domain.xml, default is computed as:

```
512 * Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() //for default Java connector
32 * Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() //for native APR connector addon
```

**max-threads:** The maximum number of request processing threads to be created by this Connector, which therefore determines the maximum number of simultaneous requests that can be handled.

**EAP 6.x:**

```
/**
 * Maximum amount of worker threads.
 */
protected int maxThreads = (org.apache.tomcat.util.Constants.LOW_MEMORY) ? 64 : ((Constants.MAX_THREADS == -1) ? 512 * Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() : Constants.MAX_THREADS);
public void setMaxThreads(int maxThreads) { this.maxThreads = maxThreads; }
public int getMaxThreads() { return maxThreads; }
```

**EAP 6.x with Native component:**

```
/**
 * Maximum amount of worker threads.
 */
protected int maxThreads = (org.apache.tomcat.util.Constants.LOW_MEMORY) ? 32 : ((Constants.MAX_THREADS == -1) ? 32 * Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() : Constants.MAX_THREADS);
public void setMaxThreads(int maxThreads) { this.maxThreads = maxThreads; }
public int getMaxThreads() { return maxThreads; }
```

I believe both are same. I have never used max-connections attribute. Whenever custom max thread count was required, I used to create separate thread factory and thread pool. for more information refer to:
[redhat doc](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.3/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/sect-Connector_Configuration.html), [SO Question Ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268924/java-waiting-connection-threads-created-by-http-connection-are-alive-for-very-l)